Fitting the 9th piece into the pizza box
I bought two pizzas that were radially sliced into 8 identical pieces each. I ate 7 of the 16 pieces. Now to save space I want to place the remaining 9 pieces into one box without cutting them and without any overlap. Is this possible?
For the sake of the puzzle, assume that pizzas are perfect unit circles and the box is a 2x2 square.

If you like this puzzle, then you might also enjoy the red circle puzzle.

Maybe a nice follow up question could be: How large does the box need to be (in relation to the pizza) when you need to fit 10 pieces?

@Ivo great question. Please post it!

posted it: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/127943/fitting-10-pieces-of-pizza-in-a-box

General solution for n pieces: feed any extra pieces that don't fit to the dog.

Do the pizza slices have to lie flat or is there enough vertical space to zigzag them up and down?

@Ivo : or to find smallest box to fit 9

What's the thickness of each pizza?   And what's the vertical height inside each box?

Timely question.  I did this just last night:

 

Desmos:

 https://www.desmos.com/calculator/psqufizida


No integer linear programming?  ;-)

Maybe next time. :)

geogebra shows a rather tight fit as well

That's correct! Are there any other solutions?

At least three others. :)

Wow cool. Let's see if anyone else can find them

@DmitryKamenetsky : there sure may be other solutions like, e.g.,  the one you gave, but the desmos given one is nice in that it's pizza piece is positioned symmetric and its tip has rational coordinates and several lengths in the geometry relate to sqrt(2) and in some way the formula tan(pi/8) = sqrt(2) -1 is also present. Not to speak about aesthetics.

@RobPratt can you post the other solutions please?

I just meant the 90-degree rotations.

This is not a proper answer, just for fun.

 This is how I solved the problem in my real life. Here the pieces are different size, so not sure if it works in the abstract sense.


 


The width of the 3 pieces on the far left ends up being 2.3 (chord length of each 1/8th * 3), so you'd need to fiddle with them quite a bit for them to fit in approximately the location they are in currently.

The first approach to this problem is to see if it is possible at all, and so the first, most trivial idea is to inscribe a circle within the 2x2 square (b/c you want to keep the shapes as close as possible with wasting and spreading area out). This gives us an inscribed unit circle since the circle's diameter would equal the square's side length.
From there, we could fit 8/9 pizza slices within the 2x2 box since eight slices = 1 unit circle of pizza. Now we need to fit one more sector with an area of pi/8 and to do this, we first see if it is at all possible and to do this, we subtract the total area of the square - the total area of a circle to get the remaining area (4-pi(1)^2) and get around 0.858 and pi/8 is less then 0.858.
Hence, it is possible, but how can we do this? The second question is if it is possible to connect these gaps; to do this, we rotate each 1x1 square to get the final solution.

 


The math you provide only shows that there is sufficient area. You should also show that the remaining area can be arranged to accommodate the slice. (The drawing alone is insufficient, since drawings do not prove scale — photos do, which is why the other answer showing this same solution is fine.)

The photo in the other solution is not proof either as the pieces overlap there. However he did prove it in desmos

I see the comments and I will rewrite this proof sorry about this inconsistency.

I just wrote an HTML canvas here:
Picture:

 

HTML:
<html lang="en">
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
</body>
</html>

JS:
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
ctx.fillStyle = "white";
ctx.strokeStyle = "white";

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(0,0,100, 0, Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(200,0,100, 0, Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(0,200,100, 0, 2*Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(200,200,100, 0, 2*Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath();
for(let i=100;i>=0;i--){
ctx.arc(174,100,i, Math.PI*2*7/16, Math.PI*2*9/16);
ctx.stroke();
}


That's cool. Is there a way to make it interactive so one can move pieces around without overlap?

I am not sure but I think answer given was 175 (not 174)

It's more of a range. 175 (or 173) would also work, but touch the other slices.
